# Function return type conflict in C

Tags: c

I am working on Average function in C. Average function is attained by using addition and division functions. That is `avg(x,y)=div(add(x,y),2)`. But the error occurs as

> "incompatible types when returning type 'div_t' but 'float' was expected"

The code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int add(int,int);
    float avg(int,int);
    float div(int,int);
    printf("%d",avg(50,20));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
float avg(int x, int y){
    return div(add(x,y),2);
}
float div(int x, int y){
    return (x/y);
}
```

Why so?

Comment: WTH you have function declaration inside `main()`?

Comment: Declare the functions before their usage at file scope, not in `main`. Enable warnings in compiler. Use C99 or C11 compiler. Read a C book about function declaration, prototypes, function usage and name scope.

Comment: The declarations inside `main()` are no longer visible when you define your functions, so your `avg()` function is probably using a completely different `div()` function, which might happen to return a `div_t` result.

Comment: Since it looks like it's for homework or something, I'll give a tip - remember div(123,0) is going to cause bad things unless you check if y is 0.

Comment: Sorry! I have tried various ways and even syntaces. I forgot to put it write whle posting the question! @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: Also, it's pretty pointless to define an `int add (int, int)` function where the `+` operator is already doing exactly the same thing (and the same applies to the `float div(int, int)`, which happens to only return integer values. Writing your average function as `float avg(int x, int y) { return (x+y)/2.f; }` would avoid these unnecessary functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that the `div` function that you've declared conflicts with a function defined in a header (`stdlib.h`).  Renaming the function to `ddiv`, for example, will fix that particular issue.

The second problem, as other commenters have noted, is that you have put forward declarations inside the body of main, so the function `avg` cannot see the definition of `ddiv`.  Best practice here is to move all the forward declarations out, or just have the `main` function declared after the definition of the other functions and omit the prototypes entirely.

The third problem, as a matter of correctness, is that your `div` function is operating on integers, so will not give the correct answer for fractional amounts (so will return `50` instead of `50.5` for `avg(50,51)`).  Instead, you either need to have the `div` function take floats, in which case the compiler will automatically do the right thing, or modify the function to compute `(float)x/y`.

The last problem is that you are using `%d` in the `printf` to print out a  floating point number. Most likely the compiler will warn about this, but if not, you will get strange behavior.  Use `%f` instead.

Comment: Thank you. But... Why the ddiv arguments should be of type float? I know that the parameters won't be float anyways according to me and the return type may or may not be float depending upon parameters. Whether it is mandatory that 'float return type' function should always have float type parameters? Why so? Any memory level or processor level mechanism involved?

Comment: The answer here is a little involved.  At some point, to give a correct answer, both parameters of `ddiv` must be converted to floats.  If the parameters are floats, then the compiler will automatically do the conversion in the `avg` function.  If the parameters are ints, then you need to explicitly tell the compiler to do the conversion, otherwise it takes the integer result of `x/y` and converts that to a float -- by then it is too late.

Answer (score 4):

> *incompatible types when returning type 'div_t' but 'float' was expected"*

This warning is because the mismatch between the prototype and definition mismatch.

**How:**

When you `#include <stdlib.h>`, the [prototype of `div()` gets included](http://linux.die.net/man/3/div). It is the implementation provided in the standard library. It says

```
div_t div(int numerator, int denominator);
```

Now, inside the code, you're (re)defining a function with the same name `div()` with a signature as

```
 float div(int x, int y)
```

So, while calling the `div()`, compiler sees the definition having a mismatch with the declaration. So it generates the warning.

**Solution:** Use a different name, like `my_div()` for *your* version. Aslo, move the forward declaration of the functions outside `main()` body.

---

Apart from the above issue, in your version of `div()` there is one issue. In

```
float div(int x, int y){
  return (x/y);
  }
```

function. here both `x`and `y` are of type `int`, so the division will be integer division, result being an `int` type. However, as you've defined the function to have a return type of `float`, return type mismatch will be generated. To resolve, you should enforce floating-point division by writing

```
return ( (float)x / y );
```

Then, inside `main()` you're using

```
printf("%d",avg(50,20));
```

i.e, `%d` format specifier to print a `float` value. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should be using `%f` to print a `float`.

Comment: Nope, implicit type conversion would be done (and no `div_t` type would be implied). I just tested it on gcc, with `-Wall -Wextra` flags, and no warnings are reported.

Comment: Not even implicit declarations, as `stdlib.h` is included in the source code, so the `div()` function is properly declared (and not shadowed by the declaration which is placed inside the `main()`)

Comment: Its explicit. The problem is it is explicit *twice* with two different return types. `div_t` is `typedef struct {int quot; int rem;} div_t;` (at least on every platform I've ever used), which is certainly *not* a `float`. That prototype in `main()` shouldn't compile. The invoke later is saying `div_t` and `float` aren't the same (and rightly so).

Comment: @SouravGhosh there is still an issue on your analysis of the `div` function: the implicit conversion from `int` to `float` does not generate any warning (it's perfectly valid behavior) ;)

Comment: Sorry, I read your 'type mismatch will be generated' as 'the compiler will warn you about type mismatch'. Indeed you're not talking about a compiler warning, my bad !

Comment: @NiBZ Nevermid, Happens !! (For me, even more, as I'm not a native English speaker and English is not much used IRL here). nevertheless, thanks for your time. :-)